# Create graph-tool Graph from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, networkx, graph-tool

I have been using networkx for a bit, and it is really neat how it lets me create Graph objects directly from dictionaries: simply `nx.Graph(my_dictionary)`. 
Now I am trying to use graph-tool, and I notice I cannot do the same.

While googling I came across [this blog post](http://bbengfort.github.io/snippets/2016/06/23/graph-tool-from-networkx.html) which shows how to create a graph-tool Graph from a networkx graph.
The process, however, is quite involved, and I would not want to depend on both a home-brewed function *and* networkx whenever I use graph-tool.

I guess it would be just as easy to write a function that iterates through my dictionary.
But before I set out doing that, I wanted to make sure nobody had already written a dict-to-graph-tool parser.
It seems like an obvious thing to do, but I can find absolutely nothing in the graph-tool docs....

Comment: What does your dictionary contain?

Comment: each vertex from which edges originate is a key, and the corresponding value is a list of the vertices where the edges point to. It seems a pretty obvious format, since networkx supports it out of the box.

Comment: I have added an answer now.

Comment: If you have found the answer to be useful, please accept it by clicking the mark near it.

Answer (score 2):

This looks quite simple. Assuming that your dictionary represents an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) of the graph (that is what you said in the comment), it can be done as follows:

```
In [3]: d # This dictionary contains the adjacency list
Out[3]: {0: [1, 2], 1: [3]}
```

You can create edge list out of it and add it to an empty graph:

```
In [4]: edges = [(i, j) for i in d for j in d[i]]

In [6]: G = gt.Graph(directed = False)

In [7]: G.add_edge_list(edges)

In [8]: G
Out[8]: <Graph object, undirected, with 4 vertices and 3 edges at 0x7fdbc8257780>
```

Which is what you wanted.